# How to debug AsyncTask.doInBackground?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am tying to use an async task in android studio to execute a php script on the same network as me and get the result.

```
private class HTTPReqTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String temp = new String();
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("PHPSCRIBT" + strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                int status = con.getResponseCode();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                temp = sb.toString();
                Log.d("myTag", temp);
                con.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return temp;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String temp) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            try {
                String erstezahl = temp.split("\\{")[0];
                String jsonstring = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("{") - 1);

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);

                int amount = Integer.valueOf(erstezahl);
                textView.setText(amount);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String error = "ERROR +" + temp + "+" + e.toString();
                textView.setText(error);
            }


        }
    }
```

My onPostExecute() function gets an empty string as a Parameter. As such I want to debug my doInBackground function. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can check the response Code andverify if api is worked correctly or not

Comment: Just set a breakpoint

Comment: Add more log statements. You have only one. What does it print?

Comment: You should print the stack trace in that catch block and add a log statement and return a string with the exception message.

Comment: `sb.append(line);` To keep the lines: `sb.append(line+"\n");`

Comment: Breakpoints dont get triggered for some reason and the log statement also doesnt work. But i have found the Problem by now.